# How To play Embed video in android google tv

Tags: android, google-tv

I Am working on android google tv project. In My project i want to play video from html embed code show below:-

```
<embed type="application/x-shockwave-flash" src="http://www.desifreetv.com/channels/tomandjerry.swf" file="http://desifreetv.com/locked/xml-files/tomandjerry.xml" width="707" height="483" style="undefined" id="mpl" name="mpl" quality="high" allowfullscreen="true" wmode="opaque" menu="false">
```

how i play

Answer (score 1):

If you have a native app and plan to use a WebView with the above snippet embedded in it, you will run into issues since WebView doesn't support flash. If your app is a browser based app, flash is supported so you should be able to embed it in your web page. Alternatively, see if the provider of that content has a differently formatted videos (say, mp4 or so) and then you can use the native players.